# Tools for continuous integration with Python

Tags: python, continuous-integration, hudson

My project is based on only Python code.We are using multiple tool for pylint,profiler for improving the code quality.So each developer need to run individually run this Tool.I am planning to integrate all tools into single script or tool. We generally integrate new tool in hudson build tool in c++ But I am not sure is it possible in Python as I recently move to Python.So I have very basic  question.

I have searched into Python and found many build tool But I could not figure out any one which can use be for integrate to plug-in.

Do we have any tool which can do our purpose and not require to have build functionality.

Somebody suggest me to write shell script rather than look for any tool.

As of now, we are not using any build tool in Python.

Comment: Please take a look at similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436787/how-would-i-start-integrating-pyflakes-with-hudson
http://hustoknow.blogspot.nl/2011/02/setting-up-pylint-on-hudson.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502345/is-it-possible-to-see-the-source-code-of-the-violating-files-in-hudson-with-viol
http://www.rhonabwy.com/wp/2009/11/04/setting-up-a-python-ci-server-with-hudson/

Answer (score 0):

You'd better follow @WoLpH comment on how to configure hudson. And I strongly advice you to switch to Jenkins, as it has a more active developer community than hudson.

About using a build tool in python, it depends on the complexity of the project you want to deploy:

- if it is a project that has only simple python dependencies, you'd better use [`virtualenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) ;
- if you need to checkout some private repositories, or make more complex arrangements on your repositories (or if you don't want to mess your shell's environment), then [`zc.buildout`](http://www.buildout.org/docs/tutorial.html) is for you ;
- if what you want is something closer to Makefile, but that you can use in a more extensible and pythonic way, then you'd better have a look at [`scons`](http://scons.org/wiki/SconsTutorial1)

In either way, you'll need to make a [`setup.py`](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html), and add support for unit testing. For unit testing in python, you'd better have a look at [nose.py](http://blog.cesarcd.com/2011/11/python-testing-with-nose-by-example.html).

Once you chose your weapons and configured your environment, jenkins (or hudson if you want to keep the old one) is pretty easy to configure.